# my api service is not building with angular universal ssr, it gives not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-universal

My service name is **ProductService** and my component is **HomeComponent**.

I am trying to call an api from **HomeComponent.ts** here my code of home component:

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.productService.getHomeData().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
  );
}
```

my **ProductService.ts** looks like this.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ProductService {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseUrl = environment.API_BASE_URL;

  getHomeData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.get(environment.API_BASE_URL + "/product/home");
  }

}
```

Now I run **npm run build:ssr**

It build my project and then run **npm run serve:ssr**

The page loads correctly in browser but there are some issues in background going on.

**Issue #1:** It does not show the content from the api when I open it in "View Page Source" in chrome.

**Issue #2:** It gives an error in the terminal which I have mentioned below.

```
ERROR TypeError: this.productService.getHomeData is not a function
    at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (/Users/project/dist/project/server/3.js:1:7570)
    at callHook (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:140488)
    at callHooks (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:140111)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:139452)
    at refreshView (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:212819)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:213616)
    at refreshView (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:213698)
    at refreshComponent (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:228936)
    at refreshChildComponents (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:214728)
    at refreshView (/Users/project/dist/project/server/main.js:1:214770)
```

**My Observations:**

#1: build:ssr is not adding functions of ProductService in the build directory.

#2: since this.productService.getHomeData is not a function in the build file, it does not runs the api while rendering in server and this is why it does not any data from API in View Page Source

Comment: Maybe create a minimal repo reproducing the issue